# AFrame example using three.js MeshStandardMaterial with maps

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I'm looking for examples of using three.js MeshStandardMaterial in AFrame with textures being applied to the other mappable parameters. I just need a hackable boilerplate example.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Until those properties are available through A-Frame, you can create a component to set those maps.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('lightmap', {
  dependencies: ['material'],

  init: {
    var material = this.el.getObject3D('mesh').material;
    material.lightmap = // ... Modify material.
  }
});
```

Then:

```
<a-entity material="..." lightmap></a-entity>
```

More info on writing components: https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/core/component.html

Comment: this is definitely in the direction. I guess I'm looking also for what goes in the "..." . I'm new to the whole component/entity model and I learn best by hacking on small functional boilerplate examples. An old VFX dog trying to learn some new tricks. (originally posted to the aframe learning slack channel)

Comment: Good to know you use boilerplates...we're looking to get more of those types of material out there.

The material piece: https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/components/material.html , we are just making the lightmap extend the material in a way.

Comment: I'm good at taking a small, fully functional example and methodically hacking changes and seeing how it works by how it breaks. When it's scattered about in snippets and fragments, I feel like I already have to know how to do it in order to learn how to do it :) Lightmaps would be great - currently I'm baking shading out of Houdini and throwing it into the src in flat shading, which is less than ideal.

Comment: I noticed that the new AFrame 0.3.0 has a clearer interface to creating user defined shaders. I will look into this as a path forward.

Comment: As of frame 0.8 there is no support for lightMap or am I missing something?